# remove duplicates based on the partitioned column from S3 partitioned data using SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

```
I have a partitioned data structure on S3 as below which store parquet files in it:

date=100000000000
date=111620200621
date=111620202258


The S3 key will look like s3://bucket-name/master/date={a numeric value}
```

I am reading the data from SPARK code as below:

`Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().parquet("s3://bucket-name/master/");`
`data.createOrReplaceTempView("master");` // This will lead to duplicates as NUM_VALUE can be repetitive in each S3 partition```

Spark DF looks like below with duplicate NUM_value:

```
NAME    date            NUM_VALUE
name1   100000000000    1
name2   111620200621    2
name3   111620202258    2
```

Expected unique output:

```
NAME    date            NUM_VALUE
name1   100000000000    1
name3   111620202258    2
```

I am trying to get the unique latest data as below:

`Dataset<Row> final = spark.sql("SELECT NAME,date,NUM_VALUE FROM  (SELECT rank() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY date DESC) rank, * FROM master)  temp WHERE (rank = 1)");`
`final.show();`

But I am getting the below error when the above query is invoked:

````
    if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 40, date), LongType) AS date#472L
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:594)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:594)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of bigint
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.If_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_0_20$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:289)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8INxj.png
````

Answer (score 1):

Read the way you are using

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().parquet("s3://bucket-name/master/")
```

To get duplicates , Use **group by()** along with **Count()** (*Returns the count of rows for each group.*) And **gt(1)** will get you all rows with duplicates.

```
 val dups = df .groupBy("NAME","date","NUM_VALUE").count.filter(col("count").gt(1));
    println(dups.count()+" rows in dups.count")
```

And if you want to remove duplicates , use **dropDuplicates**

```
 val uniqueRowsDF = df.dropDuplicates("NAME","date","NUM_VALUE")
 println(uniqueRowsDF .count()+" rows after .dropDuplicates")
```

Comment: Name and date can have different values , only NUM_VALUE will be duplicated. I have to drop the duplicates keeping the highest value in the date column, hence the RANK query in my code snippet by ordering the 'date' column in descending order